# Asymptotic behaviour of $\frac{p_n-2}{p_n}$

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, infinite-product

I am interested in how fast this prime product approaches to 0:

$$
\prod_{n=2}^{N}\frac{p_n - 2}{p_n}
$$

Where $p_n$ is the nth prime number.

Numerical computation suggests that for $N > 1312$, $k = 0.5$
we have the following upper bound:

$$
\prod_{n=2}^{N}\frac{p_n - 2}{p_n} > \frac{1}{p_N^{k}}
$$

Can anyone prove this?

Comment: your product is bounded between $\frac{0.813566}{\ln^2 N}$ and $\frac{0.842741}{\ln^2 N}$ so the product is bigger than $\frac{1}{N^{\epsilon}}$ for every $\epsilon >0$ and $N$ sufficiently large number.

Comment: You can make a heuristic argument using $\dfrac{p_n - 2}{p_n} = 1 - \dfrac{2}{p_n} \approx e^{-\frac{2}{p_n}}$ and the [Meissel–Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $n \ln n < p_n $ for all $n\geq 1$ and you are looking for lower bound so $\prod \limits_{n=2}^{N} (1-\frac{2}{p_n}) = \frac{1}{5} \prod \limits_{n=4}^{N} (1-\frac{2}{p_n}) \geq 0.2 \prod \limits_{n=4}^{N} (1-\frac{2}{n \ln n}) = 0.2 e^{\sum \limits_{n=4}^{N} \ln(1-\frac{2}{n \ln n})}$ and since $\ln(1-\frac{2}{t}) > -\frac{3}{t}$ for all $t>3.44$ and that $n \ln n > 3.44$ for all $n\geq 4$.

So we are left with $0.2 e^{-3 \sum \limits_{n=4}^{N} \frac{1}{n \ln n}}$

$\frac{1}{n \ln n}$ is monotonic deceasing function so we can bound the summation by integral, and we get that $0.2 e^{-3 \sum \limits_{n=4}^{N} \frac{1}{n \ln n}} \geq 0.2 e^{-3 \int \limits_{4}^{N} \frac{1}{n \ln n}dn}$

and $0.2 e^{-3 \int \limits_{4}^{N} \frac{1}{n \ln n}dn} = 0.2 e^{-3(\ln \ln N-\ln \ln 4)}$ since $\int \frac{1}{n \ln n} dn = \ln \ln n+C$

Now we are left with $0.2 e^{-3(\ln \ln N-\ln \ln 4)} = \frac{\ln^3(4)}{5 \ln^3(N)} \approx \frac{0.53284}{\ln ^3 N} > \frac{1}{p_N^{0.5}}$ for all $N>10^7$

Actually a very good approach using Dusart result about the sum  $ \ln \ln x +B -\frac{1}{2 \ln^2 x}<\sum \limits_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} < \ln \ln x +B +\frac{1}{2 \ln^2 x}$ for $x>300$ where $B \approx 0.2614972128476427$ is Meissel–Mertens constant, one can bound your product by :

$\frac{0.814886}{\ln^2 p_N} <\prod \limits_{n=2}^{N} (1-\frac{2}{p_n}) < \frac{0.843639}{\ln^2 p_N}$

And the exact value is $c = \lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \ln^2 p_N \prod \limits_{n=2}^{N} (1-\frac{2}{p_n}) \approx 0.832417$

in this case $\prod \limits_{n=2}^{N} (1-\frac{2}{p_n}) > \frac{0.814886}{\ln^2 p_N} > \frac{1}{p_N^{0.5}}$ for all $N>1388$ , by computer checking for all $1388 \geq N \geq 1312$ one conclude that its true for all $N>1312$.

Comment: I accepted your answer.  Very well explained. Thank you very much!